# Modifying JVM built in class loaders

Tags: jvm, classloader, java

If I obtained a copy of the OpenJDK and wished to edit the built in class loaders of the JVM, such as the system class loader or the bootstrap class loader (Mainly for academic and curiosity reasons) would I be able to do this? If so, where are these class loaders stored in the source code?

Comment: Those are written in native language. Why dont you write your custom classloader instead of playing around with bootstrap loader?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to take a copy of the Java code for the built class loaders, these are in src.zip.  Once you have modified these classes you can be added to lib/endorsed in JAR.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/standards/

Instead of having to compile the entire source, you only need to modify one class or so.

This is not allowed under the terms of use nor supportable, so I suggest you **only** do this for educational purpose.